# How to assing model() to QListView

Tags: python, pyqt

The code below creates a single `QListView`. An instance of `MyClass` (it is inherited from QAbstractListModel) is assigned to its `self.setModel(self.model)`. If I click the view I can select the items in a list (so they do exist). But no names of the items displayed. How do I control how the QListView items are displayed?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyClass(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.elements={'Animals':['Bison','Panther','Elephant'],'Birds':['Duck','Hawk','Pigeon'],'Fish':['Shark','Salmon','Piranha']}
    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.elements)        
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        print'MyClass.data():',index,role

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model=MyClass()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.show()

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use a dictionary for the elements, but using lists:

```
    self.elements=['Bison','Panther','Elephant','Duck','Hawk','Pigeon','Shark','Salmon','Piranha']
```

You just have to return `self.elements[index.row()]` in the `data()` method. For instance:

```
class MyClass(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.elements=['Bison','Panther','Elephant','Duck','Hawk','Pigeon','Shark','Salmon','Piranha']
    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.elements)        
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        print'MyClass.data():',index,role
        if index.isValid() and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(self.elements[index.row()])
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()
```